# c# variable into sql command

Tags: c#, sql

```
string alpha="this is text";
string sql = "INSERT INTO dokimastikospinakas (pliroforia) VALUES ('alpha')";
```

Which is the right syntax to pass a c# variable into an sql command?

Comment: What does your research tell you? http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+variable+into+sql+command

Comment: See the paramaterized example;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000/c-sqlclient-simplest-insert

Comment: This must be the easiest c#/sql question to answer with google.  have you made *any* effort?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's just one very simple method:

```
var yourTextValue = "this is text";
using (var db = new SqlConnection()) {
    db.Open();

    var command =
        new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dokimastikospinakas (pliroforia) VALUES (@textValue);", db);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textValue", yourTextValue);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**EDIT**: You'd actually need some connection string for `SqlConnection` constructor, of course. And modified variable names by popular demand.

Comment: I think the `@id` variable name is a bit weak, but the answer is correct.

Comment: Using "id" for a string variable?

Comment: I mean, since I don't know what a pliroforia is I couldn't infer context. I guess I could have called the variable `@phlargosmarfin` instead.

Comment: @Yuck:  Yes you could have.. and it would garner much more votes for the laugh. ;) +1

Answer (score 3):

To avoid sql injection vulnerabilities, I recommend:

```
string alpha="this is text";
SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
sqlComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dokimastikospinakas (pliroforia) VALUES (@var)";
sqlComm.AddWithValue("@var", alpha);
```

..etc.

Comment: sqlComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dokimastikospinakas (pliroforia) VALUES ('@var')" would not work!  You need to take out those single quotes from @var in that statement!

Answer (score 2):

Look into using parameterized queries.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Parameters.Add("@alpha").Value = alpha;
command.CommandText = sql;
```

And your query would look like:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO dokimastikospinakas (pliroforia) VALUES (@alpha)";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO dokimastikospinakas (pliroforia) VALUES (@alpha)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insert, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@alpha", alpha);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ADO.NET? Then parameterized queries are what you want:

```
IDbCommand command = new IDbCommand();
// Set up command connection
command.Text = "INSERT INTO dokimastikospinakas (pliroforia) VALUES (@alpha)";
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@alpha", alpha));
```

The above code snippet of course depends on the type of database you are using (especially which type of SqlParameter you add.

Answer (score 0):

Example using a OracleCommand object:
OraCon is the OracleConnection.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO dokimastikospinakas (pliroforia) VALUES ( :Alpha )";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, OraCon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(":Alpha", alpha);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string alpha;
string sql = "INSERT INTO dokimastikospinakas (pliroforia) VALUES ('" + alpha + "')";
```

this is the easiest way to do it, but it is not safe from SQL injection attacks. Instead, you should first check the value of `alpha` to ensure it is safe to use in a query.