# How To Save A Single SQL Entry As A Variable?

Tags: c#, sql

Lets say I have the following DataBase

Table Name: Users

---

```
ID |  Name  |  Surname  |
1  |  Peter |  Parker   |
2  |  Hulk  |  Hogan    |
```

---

```
        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
        using (SqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            Command.CommandText = "SELECT FROM Users WHERE ID='2'";

            //......
        }
```

The following command will Select Hulk Hogan entry.

If I wanted to save his surname/name as a string, how would I have to do it?

```
string Surname = ....;
SurnameTextBox.Text = Surname; // Displays - Hogan
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should think in using EF instead here is a [good video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhUPBSX-E2aJCnCR3-_6zBZx)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I do not think he _should_. He _could_ but Entity Framework and ORM/s in general are not always the best tool for the job. Myself and many others prefer to use a Micro OR/M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get multi column use `SqlDataReader` like this:

```
string name="";
string surname="";

using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
   Connection.Open();//Don't forget this line else you get "InvalidOperationException"
   using (SqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand())
   {        
      Command.CommandText = "SELECT name,surname FROM Users WHERE ID=2";
      using (SqlDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
      {
         reader.Read();
         name = reader.GetString(0);
         surname= reader.GetString(1);
      }
   }
}

NameTextBox.Text = name;
SurnameTextBox.Text = surname;
```

Also if You want to get one row with one column value with your query.
just need to use `ExecuteScalar` like this:

```
string name="";

using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
   using (SqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand())
   {
      Connection.Open();
       Command.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM Users WHERE ID=2";
       name = Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you were much! Will definitely help!

Answer (score 2):

You would do something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    using (SqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        Command.CommandText = "SELECT Name, Surname FROM Users WHERE ID='2'";
        using (SqlDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string Surname = (string) reader["Surname"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code, unlike the other posts, is not using `reader.GetString()`. Instead its accessing it by its column name. My code has the advantage in that you can `SELECT` your columns in any order. For example, all of these select statements will still return `Surname`:

```
 Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID='2'";
 Command.CommandText = "SELECT Surname, Name FROM Users WHERE ID='2'";
 Command.CommandText = "SELECT Name, Surname FROM Users WHERE ID='2'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your column names in your sql as;

```
SELECT Name, Surname FROM Users WHERE ID='2'
```

and you can use [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get these values like;

```
string name, surname;
using(var reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
{
   while(reader.Read())
   {
       name = reader.GetString(0); // Hulk
       surname = reader.GetString(1); // Hogan
   }
}
```

Comment: name/surname must be outside the while/using block

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (SqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand())
{
    Command.CommandText = "SELECT Name, Surname FROM Users WHERE ID='2'";
    using(SqlDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        reader.Read();
        var name = reader.GetString(0);
        var surname = reader.GetString(1);
        NameTextBox.Text = name;
        SurnameTextBox.Text = surname;
    }
}
```

Your command syntax is invalid. You did not specify any columns to return in the result table. I fixed that for you in the above example.

Now that you have a valid query, you need to execute it. You can execute the query using `ExecuteReader`.

`ExecuteReader` returns a `SqlDataReader`. Use this reader to read rows from the result table.

You access the columns by their column index (in this case, name (0) and surname (1)):

Comment: Thank you! From what I can understand [0] represents the Name and [1] Surname? Like in an array?

Comment: It worked perfectly! What If I wanted to search based on a passed variable? Lets say I have a (string name = ,,, ; )
SELECT FROM Users WHERE Name=' " + name + " ' ";

Can you use something similar to ("{0}", name) ?

Comment: Yes, you can but if the `name` is coming from the user and it is a central database, **you must be _very_ wary of SQL injection**. The safe way to do this is using parameters. You can find an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7080640/5147646). If this answer worked then please consider marking it as accepted :D

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `ExecuteScalar()`

```
Surname = Command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Change your query to implicitly select Surname.

Comment: I did not down vote but as I understand it, `ExecuteScalar` only returns the first column. OP wants both columns.

Comment: Yes, I just reread the comment and notice he mentioned surename/name. We all make mistakes :-)