# How can I save my Textbox content in a database? Textbox is programmed in HTML and CSS

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, textbox

I have a fully finished Frontend of my Web Application, now i have to save the textbox content in my Database(SQL) wich i created in VisualStudio.

My ConnectionString is already programmed
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og0pa.png)
I coded my textbox as following:

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxTG2.png)

How do i have to integrate my C# in my Html code so it saves my Content?

Thanks for your time <3

Comment: What exactly do you need to know? Have you created a table in the database to store those values? Would you want to use Entity Framework or ADO? In order to help, I think we need more content from your question

Comment: The Tabels are created, what i need to know:

Comment: How to store my Data in the Database. It should save it as soon as i press a "next" button". What i also want to know is how i have to set this all up in my html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in whichever event you want it to execute in:

```
string con = //your connection string here
string yourTextValue = Passnummer.Text; //This will extract the text from your textbox and store it in a variable
using (string con = new SqlConnection()) {
con.Open();

var command =
    new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO yourTable(columnname) VALUES (@textValue);", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textValue", yourTextValue);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
}
```

See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080589/c-sharp-variable-into-sql-command)

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. Do you know any way on how i can save my textbox value, in a variable?

Comment: string yourTextValue is your variable in this case 

So what you do is take say:

string yourTextValue = yourtextboxname.Text;

this will take what is in your textbox and store it in the variable (as soon as your event is fired) So say you want to do this in a button click, you insert the code above in to the button click method, as soon as you click your button it will look at your textbox and store whatever is currently in there to the variable